# How can I setup PIDs using ffmpeg & MP4 Container?

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, mp4

Is there anyone who could help me with a simple hint regarding MP4 container?

Basically I got all the results I need, I just need a help to understand how to define PIDs (or component IDs) for each track inside the container.

The command I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -i source.mov -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -b:v 20000K -minrate 20000K -maxrate 20000K -bufsize 40000K -bf 2 -qcomp 0.0 -keyint_min 25  -g 15 -pix_fmt yuv420p -color_trc bt709 -color_primaries bt709 -r 30000/1001 -profile:v high -level 4.1 -bsf:v 'filter_units=remove_types=6' -movflags faststart -metadata:s:v:0 language=eng -metadata:s:v:0 title="Video" -filter_complex "[0] scale=1920:1080" -filter_complex "[0:3][0:1][0:2][0:4][0:5][0:6]join=inputs=6:channel_layout=5.1,loudnorm=I=-23:TP=-1.0:LRA=20" -filter_complex "[0:9][0:7][0:8][0:10][0:11][0:12]join=inputs=6:channel_layout=5.1,loudnorm=I=-23:TP=-1.0:LRA=20" -c:a ac3 -b:a:0 448k -b:a:1 448k -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -metadata:s:a:0 title="AC-3 5.1" -metadata:s:a:1 language=por -metadata:s:a:1 title="AC-3 5.1" -streamid 0:0x01E1 -streamid 1:0x01E2 -streamid 2:0x01E3 -f mp4 output.mp4
```

My output file is a MP4 but tracks IDs are 1 (video), 2 (1st audio), 3 (2nd audio).

How can I change these IDs to 101, 201 and 202?

Many thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Add `-use_stream_ids_as_track_ids true`. At this time, check the resulting track id in Mediainfo, ffmpeg won't show it.

Comment: many thanks, gyan! problem solved. cheers!